# get current url 0th index value in angular 7

Tags: angular

The url is 
 http://localhost:4200/horizontal/ecommerce/product-edit/men/2
I want to get horizontal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url is string not url object, you can split by / and get index like this.

```
var url = 'http://localhost:4200/horizontal/ecommerce/product-edit/men/2'
    var arr = url.split("/");
    console.log(arr[3])
```

If your url is in browser, you can use

```
var first = location.pathname.split('/')[1];
console.log(first);
```

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:4200/horizontal/ecommerce/product-edit/men/2'
var arr = url.split("/");
console.log(arr[3])
```